# Unable to get laravel/database and restler working with versioning

Tags: laravel-4, restler

I have an existing website up and running, and now I want to add a REST interface to it in an api subdirectory.  I'm not able to get this to work with versioning.  I installed like so (no errors):

```
$ php ~/bin/composer.phar create-project laravel/database --prefer-dist api
$ cd api
$ php ~/bin/composer.phar require restler/framework 3.0.0-RC6
```

Then I uncommented the lines in public/index.php related to Restler and add a new API class that just echos a string.  If I run this via `php artisan serve` and look at it through the localhost URL, then the method works.

Now I want to enable versioning, so I added these lines to public/index.php

```
use Luracast\Restler\Defaults;
Defaults::$useUrlBasedVersioning = true;
```

And in app/controllers I created a v1 directory and moved Test.php into that.  I also added a namespace directive to the file of the format `namespace A\B\v1`

When I restart the artisan server and query the API, I get a 404 error.  I've tried as both `http://localhost:8000/Test` and `http://localhost:8000/v1/Test`

What have I forgotten to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I made it to work. Note the folder where I placed the api class file.

in index.php

```
use Luracast\Restler\Restler;
use Luracast\Restler\Defaults;
Defaults::$useUrlBasedVersioning = true;

$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('A\B\Test');
```

Test.php kept in `app/controllers/A/B/v1/Test.php`

```
<?php namespace A\B\v1;

class Test
{
    public function get()
    {
        return 'working';
    }
}
```

Both `http://localhost:8000/v1/test` and `http://localhost:8000/test` return `"working"`

Comment: @Luracast: I have added $r->addAPIClass('Luracast\\Restler\\Resources'); line in index.php so that I can use explore/documentation but it is not working & gives 500 Internal Server Error ..

Also I tried to comment the line require_once '../../../vendor/restler.php'; in  actual restler examples & it gives the same 500 Internal Server Error

so I try to add that file ( from examples ) to existing but still it wont work for me ... Can you plz help